# amsmath fleqn doesn't work?

Tags: amsmath

I would like to have my equations left aligned. I use fleqn to achieve this, but unfortunately, it seems everything is getting right aligned? I really don't know why this happens. Can someone help me out please?

My code:

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[Gray, squaren, thinqspace, thinspace]{SIunits}

\begin{align*}
    \frac{dm}{dt} = \unit{30560}{kg/u} \\
    \rho = \unit{957}{kg/m^3} \\
    D_{extern} = \unit{114,3}{mm} \text{(Uitwendige diameter van de leiding)} \\
    d = \unit{2,9}{mm} \text{(Dikte van de leiding)}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: you are using "fleq" not "fleqn".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

welcome to tex.sx.

you have specified the option `[fleq]` instead of `[fleqn]`, but i suspect
that is just a typo.

however, you haven't specified any alignment point, so it is assumed that
these lines will be aligned at the right, since it's usually the case that
alignment is on a sign of relation, in the middle.

to align on the left, put an `&` at the beginning of each line in the
`align` group:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[Gray, squaren, thinqspace, thinspace]{SIunits}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  & \frac{dm}{dt} = \unit{30560}{kg/u} \\
  & \rho = \unit{957}{kg/m^3} \\
  & D_{extern} = \unit{114,3}{mm} \text{(Uitwendige diameter van de leiding)} \\
  & d = \unit{2,9}{mm} \text{(Dikte van de leiding)}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]